# php trying to download csv file returns page content

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to download csv file from path i saved earlier and when I am tryed to download its downloaded the right name file but inside  have the source code of the page I am doing the action from .

my code :

```
    $filename = '1515613698_250';
$path = ''.$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/'.$filename.'.csv';
    echo $path;
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '.csv"');
readfile($path);
```

When I open the csv file its showing the source code of the html .
I tried to search all the website ,Help ?

Comment: is `echo $path;` a mistake?

Comment: @Scuzzy No its correct

Comment: Well you can't echo text before sending headers, or the headers won't be sent to tell the browser how to display your CSV document. Your code appears to be fine after removing the echo, the only thing I'd question is ensuring the file is actually at `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` perhaps use `.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.` instead of `.'/'.` Otheriwse I don't see an issue.

Comment: If you are echoing anything in your PHP that will be displayed on the page, regardless if you set the headers to a csv file or not. When you echo $path; , the url of the $path will be displayed. All you have to do is simply not echo any of the code you don't want shown I imagine. You also have to set your headers before you can echo anything. As soon as there is one character displayed on a webpage, the header information has already been sent to the browser. Once you send 1 character to the browser, it will read it as a header status 200 OK (webpage) and won't change it to update to a CSV